# Extracting specific src attributes from script tags

Tags: python, regex

I want to get JS file names from the input content which contains `jquery` as a substring by RE.

This is my code:

Step 1: Extract JS file from the content.

```
>>> data = """    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_bsub.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_core.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_explore.js"/>
...     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_qaa.js"/>"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('src="js/([^"]+)"', data)
['jquery-1.9.1.min.js', 'jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js', 'abc_bsub.js', 'abc_core.js', 'abc_explore.js', 'abc_qaa.js']
```

Step 2: Get JS file which have sub string as `jquery`

```
>>> [ii for ii in re.findall('src="js/([^"]+)"', data) if "jquery" in ii]
['jquery-1.9.1.min.js', 'jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js']
```

Can I do above Step 2 in the Step 1 means RE Pattern to get result?

Comment: Is the word `jquery` always in the beginning of the file name?

Comment: I think yes, all jquery library file names are start with `jquery` word, but if they change file naming structure then we have to update code.

Comment: `[ele["src"] for ele in BeautifulSoup(data).find_all("script",src=re.compile(r"\bjquery\b"))]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes `HTML Parser` are one other way, I will go with `lxml` and `xpth` method to get result. but RE is better then parser(RunTime)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can. One way would be to use

```
re.findall('src="js/([^"]*jquery[^"]*)"', data)
```

This will match everything after `"js/` until the nearest `"` if it contains `jquery` anywhere. If you know more about the position of `jquery` (for example, if it's always at the start) you can adjust the regex accordingly.

If you want to make sure that `jquery` is not directly surrounded by other alphanumeric characters, use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
re.findall(r'src="js/([^"]*\bjquery\b[^"]*)"', data)
```

Comment: Good work Doc, even Enginners struggle to do this :)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thank you. +1